# How are Ubuntu snaps updated and upgraded?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I know I can upgrade an individual snap with the `sudo snap refresh $SNAPNAME` command, but I'm wondering whether there is a single command to upgrade all snaps at once.

Or are they upgraded automatically? And if so, how often and when?

Answer (score 8):

From snapd 2.0.8 (available in Ubuntu 16.04 updates), there is a new command (`snap refresh`) that refreshes all snaps.

This command is run automatically daily.

This was announced in the [snapcraft mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snapcraft/2016-June/000182.html).

Comment: It's mentioned in bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1588322 at least.